# asp.net generate Gridview by DropDownList IndexChange

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to generate a `GridView` and fill it by `DropDownList` `SelectedValue`

I have a `DropDownList` bind to **Country** data table and `GridView` bind to **State** data table  and by changing the value of the `DropDownList` the data in the `GridView` change too

i'v tried this code:
this to fill the dropdownlist:

```
protected void FillDropdownList()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Country", con);
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(dt);
        DropDownListCountry.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownListCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        DropDownListCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        DropDownListCountry.DataBind();
        //DropDownListCountry.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select --");
        //OR    ddlEmpRecord.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Emp Id", "-1"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        adp.Dispose();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and this to generate the `gridView`

```
 protected void BindGrid()
{

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select *  from State where CountryID='" + DropDownListCountry.SelectedValue + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

and finally that's where i'm calling the functions:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    { 
        FillDropdownList();

    }
}



 protected void DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();   
}
```

the .aspx file:

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCountry" runat="server"  DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />

                    <!-- SqldataSource and GridView and Formview for State -->

        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
             <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State Id" DataField="StateID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State Name" DataField="StateName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country Id" DataField="CountryID" />
        
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

but **the code is not working** and when i'm changing the value of `DropDownList` the `GridView` is not changing

Comment: Place a break point in BindGrid() and step through the code.What happens?What's the value of dt.Rows.Count?

Comment: Does DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged fire or not at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Dropdownlist set `AutoPostBack = true`